# String primary keys for Sails fixtures

Tags: testing, sails.js, fixtures

Does Sails have working database fixtures module, that can work with string primary keys? Because [Barrels](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels) are not :( I try to find any working module but it is tons of trash only.

BTW: Anybody work with Sails in production at all? All question about Sails aren`t answered in Sails github, or gitter or stack. It seems that Sails project are dead and not used in production?

Issues in sails and waterline github are not solved for years...

Bad luck I choose it for real project.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to use string attribute and set it as primaryKey:

```
attributes: {
   stringKey: {
   type: string,
   primaryKey: true
  }
}
```

> BTW: Anybody work with Sails in production at all? All question about
>   Sails aren`t answered in Sails github, or gitter or stack. It seems
>   that Sails project are dead and not used in production?

I don't believe you asked this questions. Sails is going to be released in 1.0 finally. They are developing it and even if community support was not great, I would say it is growing and becoming better as they are fixing some crucial things like e.g. upgrade to Express 5.
Sails is definitely not dead!

Comment: Did you try Barrels? https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels It owrks fine with int, but not with strings. I seek for some analog.

Comment: Why you need it? Maybe attribute with UNIQUE would be good enough work around?